# What is the principle of this code with i++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, post-increment

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10)
        if (i++ % 2 == 0)
            cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3
5
7
9
```

Since i is 1, I thought that the *if* statement satisfies 2% 2 == 0 and 2 should be output, but why 3?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It's post increment, so it uses the _old_ value of `i` for the `%` operator.

Comment: `i++` evaluates to the value of `i` before the increment, so for `2` being the dividend you get `i == 3` in the statement of the `if` (the `cout << i << endl;` part).

Comment: Good opportunity to familiarize yourself with the number 2 programmer productivity tool: The debugger. With a debugger you can run the program at your speed and watch what the computer does with your program as it does it. Typical usage is to step through the program line by line and keep an eye out for the unexpected like the wrong value being stored or the wrong path being taken. The unexpected is a bug in the program or your expectations. Either needs to be fixed before you can continue.

Answer (score 1):

`if (i++ % 2 == 0)` means evaluate `i%2` and compare to `0`, and increment `i` at some point after evaluating it but **before** `cout << i`

That's why you're seeing odd numbers printed. In every case, an even value of `i` caused the statement controlled by the `if` to be executed, and the increment changed the even value to an odd one.

Comment: Oh wow I didnt know that the increment value persists in new iterations...even though it's a conditional increment? Very interesting!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @Cataster. `i++` and `++i` increment `i` unconditionally. The difference is whether the value is incremented before or after evaluation.

Comment: I meant like the increment happening in the condition seems to update the value of i outside the if statement correct?

Comment: @Cataster The increment happens at the moment you perform it. In this case, the result of using post-increment is the *old* value, that is what you are then comparing with `%`. By the time you reach the `cout`, the increment has already happened. That has nothing to do with the `if`

Comment: @Cataster I wouldn't want to try to pin it down in those terms. Modern compilers are quite clever in what they do, and they're capable of re-ordering instructions in quite complex ways. Let's just say that the increment happens after `i` is evaluated and before the `cout` or `while`  statements are executed. The simple answer, though, at the risk of being over simplistic, is that the increment is "part of the if"

Comment: @caster, when you do `i++`, you essentially call a function like `int operator++(int& i)` and inside the function, it will do `int temp = i; i += 1; return temp;`  So `i` is updated as soo as you do `i++`, but the value returned from `i++` is the old value of `i`, not the new one.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah I see, good to know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using **post-increment**, which increments the variable and then returns the *old* value before the increment.  You are then printing the *incremented* value.

So, lets look at your loop step-by-step:

- On the 1st iteration, `i` is 1. `i++` sets `i` to `2`, but returns `1`. So the `if` compares `1 % 2 == 0`, which is false.
- On the 2nd iteration, `i` is 2. `i++` sets `i` to `3`, but returns `2`. So the `if` compares `2 % 2 == 0`, which is true, so `cout << i` prints `3`.
- On the 3rd iteration, `i` is 3. `i++` sets `i` to `4`, but returns `3`. So the `if` compares `3 % 2 == 0`, which is false.
- On the 4th iteration, `i` is 4. `i++` sets `i` to `5`, but returns `4`. So the `if` compares `4 % 2 == 0`, which is true, so `cout << i` prints `5`.
- And so on...

It sounds like perhaps you were expecting `i++` to **pre-increment** instead, returning the *new* value rather than the *old* value.  In which case, there is a slightly different syntax for that purpose:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10)
        if (++i % 2 == 0) // <-- ++i vs i++
            cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note the position of `++` in relation to `i`.  Both syntaxes increment `i`, but positioning `++` *to the left of* `i` returns the *new* value after `i` is incremented, while positioning `++` *to the right of* `i` returns the *old* value before `i` was incremented.

Same with the decrement operator `--`, too.  It has **pre-decrement** and **post-decrement** versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ 14 Standard (5.2.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 **The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its
> operand.** [ Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value
> — end note ] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the
> operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a complete object
> type. **The value of the operand object is modified by adding 1 to
> it**, unless the object is of type bool, in which case it is set to
> true.

So for example in the second iteration of the while loop the variable `i` is indeed equal to `2` after incrementing it in the first iteration of the loop

```
while (i < 10)
    if (i++ % 2 == 0)
        cout << i << endl;
```

Thus the condition of the if statement

```
    if (i++ % 2 == 0)
```

evaluates to true. But the value of the variable `i` after the evaluation of the condition was incremented. So this statement

```
        cout << i << endl;
```

outputs the new value 3.

You can equivalently rewrite the while loop the following way

```
while (i < 10)
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        cout << ++i << endl;
    else
        ++i;
```